# How can I troubleshoot extremely slow rake assets:precompile on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets

`rake assets:precompile` is fast (<10 seconds) both locally and when I run it on heroku:

`heroku run time rake assets:precompile --trace` (clean first)

During deploy to heroku it takes around 10 minutes.

How do I figure out what the problem is here and fix it?

For reference I have tried all these:

- [rake assets:precompile is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537474/rake-assetsprecompile-is-slow) (Tried turbo-sprockets-rails3 and it did not fix the issue)
- [rake assets:precompile taking extremely long to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739654/rake-assetsprecompile-taking-extremely-long-to-complete) (Tried YUI, no go)
- [Why is assets:precompile so slow on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448401/why-is-assetsprecompile-so-slow-on-heroku) (We are on ruby 2)

We are on Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 2.0.0p353

Comment: Got some gists of the trace/gemfile? If you are using something like turbo-sprockets-rails, then you should see fast local compiles as long as you are only working with a partial recompilation.

Answer (score 0):

You should try storing your assets in memcached/redis database so you only need to compile the ones that have changed in each release you deploy:

Setup a redis/memcached database w/ Heroku (http://addons.heroku.com/) or use the one you already have

Configure an Asset cache store (via `config/environments/production.rb`):

```
config.assets.cache_store = [ :redis_store,  {
  url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] || 'redis://127.0.0.1/0',
  namespace: 'assets'
}]
```

We have been able to get our asset precompilations times down < 30sec using this method from several minutes.

Comment: This does not address the root problem and only works until you change some asset related configuration and need to recompile everything.